# Python - my if condition doesn't work in ASCII Character Set

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am writing program that takes an input from the user if they enter string with an integer, so it eliminates all the integer & print only the characters.

```
letters = input("Enter Some Word Here: ")
ans = ""
for letter in letters:
x = ord(letter)
print(x)
if 65 <= x >= 90 or 97 <= x >= 122 or x == 32:
    ans += letter
print(ans)
```

The `if condition` statement works when I check lowercase characters (`97 <= x >= 122`) or spaces (`x == 32`), but it doesn't work with capital letters (`65 <= x >= 90`).

Comment: condition should be `(65 <= x <= 90)` not `(65 <= x >= 90)`

Comment: Aside from your mistake, I would do this differently, like `print(letter for letter in letters if letter.isalpha() or letter==' ')`

Comment: @DanielH It evaluates to `True` if `x` is greater than `122`. It basically means `97 <= x and x >= 122`, which is equivalent to `122 <= x`.

Comment: @Rightleg No, it works for things between 97 and 122.

Comment: @Rightleg It works with 100 for both the OP and my testing. I think it’s parsing as `(65 <= x >= 90) or (97 <= x >= 122) or (x == 32)`, which simplifies to `x >= 90 or x >= 122 or x == 32`.

Comment: Rewrite both in regards to `x`. `x >= 97` and `x>=122`. So anything greater than 122 will be `True`

Comment: @DanielH Okay. In your first comment, you were only talking about `97 <= x >= 122`... I did not really care to try that `if` clause, because the logic is polluted by that `<= x >=` monster.

Comment: @Rightleg Yeah, I was confused in my first comment, which I have now deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if `x` is between `65` and `90` inc., you should write `65 <= x <= 90`, and also it might make your code clearer if you wrote `ord('A')` instead of  `65` and `ord('Z')` instead of `90`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to check for a letter is with `x.isalpha()`. This is clearer than using magic numbers for ordinal values, and works if you ever want to run your code for languages other than English (or even if you just want to use any [words with accented characters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_with_diacritics).

Failing that, you should at least be comparing to `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'`, `'z'`, and `' '` directly; you can compare characters with `<=` and `>=`.

What you want is “`'A'` is less than or equal to `letter` and `x` is less than or equal to '`Z`'”, which is expressed as `'A' <= letter <= 'Z'`, like in regular math. What you have, `65 <= x >= 90`, means that you want `x` to greater than or equal to 65 and greater than or equal to 90; this is the same as it just being greater than or equal to 90.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.  See also: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)